# What is the name of the problem where a bunch of people leave a party with the wrong hat?

Tags: combinatorics

In one of my math courses in university, we studied a problem where a number of people show up to a party, wearing hats. Each left with the wrong hat. I am pretty sure that there was some specific name for this problem.

What is the problem called? I would like to use this to calculate some Secret Santa matchings, so that nobody gets matched with themselves.

Comment: I've not heard a name for such problems, but the permutations involved (ones with no fixed point) are called [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: [Envelope matching problem](http://forums.oreilly.com/topic/2590-classic-envelope-matching-problem/) ? BTW, the title made me laugh, +1 for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like the *problème des rencontres* or the *derangement problem*:

> How many permutations $\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n$ have no fixed points, that is, $\pi(i)\ne i$ for all $i\in [n]$?

I've also heard it called the *hat-check problem*.

The above quotation is from Richard Stanley, *Enumerative combinatorics 1*, p. 67.  He analyzes the problem using the principle of inclusion and exclusion and attributes its first solution to Montmort.

Answer (score 2):

[D.J.S. Robinson](http://books.google.com/books?id=OVkoCcszEZ0C&pg=PA39&dq=hat) calls one such problem *the hat problem*.